# linux script to check if file exists at a particular directory more than an hour

Tags: shell, sh

I am not very good with the scripts that's why I am posting this question.

All I want to do is to check if `/path/to/my/directory/` contains any file for more than an hour. If it exist more than an hour then script should return true else false so than I can send an email if script return true.

It is kind of a alert script.

I found this script:

```
if ls /path/to/your/files* 1> /dev/null 2>&1; then
    echo "files do exist"
else
    echo "files do not exist"
fi
```

but I think this script only check whether the directory contains any file or not.

**But in my case I have to return true only if the directory contain any file for more than hour.**

**UPDATE:**  As suggested I made some small changes in my script and it is working fine(If I run the script file manually).

**myscript.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ `find /opt/coldfusion2018/cfusion/Mail/Undelivr/ -type f -mmin +60 | wc -l` -gt 0 ]];then
        echo "files do exist"
        sendmail myemail@gmail.com  < /demo/email.txt
else
        echo "files do not exist"
fi
```

**Problem:** I am trying to setup the crontab that executes this script(myscript.sh) at every 5min. But it is not working through the crontab, If I manually run the script then it works and I also get the mail.

This is the command:

```
./demo/myscript.sh
```

Corntab:

```
*/5 * * * * ./demo/myscript.sh
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ `find /path/to/my/directory/ -type f -mmin +60 | wc -l` -gt 0 ]];then
        echo "files do exist"
else
        echo "files do not exist"
fi
```

Explain: i will find all files under directory: /path/to/my/directory/ with modify time greater than 60 minutes then count them.

Comment: Thanks for replying, one small question if I want to return true or false for email purpose so I can replace echo statement with return true or false right?

Comment: Actually, you can simly add the send mail command after/before "echo" stament, keep the "echo" statement is ok (Just need to remember to redirect the output message to somewhere in case you add the script to crontab). Of course you can  replace the "echo" statement by "return [something]", but for me, that is unneccessary with your objective. It will make sense if you want to process or run some others logic base on the exit code of above section.

Comment: This is working fine email part is also working, but the problem is this only works fine if I run this script manually, but not working if I try to run this script from crontab.
`*/5 * * * * ./demo/myscipt.sh`

Comment: in order to run script in crontab; you should load the enviroment variable into the script or   use the Absolute path of command

Comment: I update the question please check, script is running through crontab but sendmail is not working.

Answer (score 0):

This one should do the thing too:

`[ "$(find /path/to/my/directory/ -type f -mmin +60)" ] && echo "files do exist" || echo "files do not exist"`

Good luck :)